# URL for custom cursor not found

Tags: html, css

I've written some code to create a custom cursor from a `.png` file.
The program doesn't work and when I open the developer console, I found out that the page had modified the supplied URL by removing the backslashes, adding some weird symbols in between and the console displays that it can't find the specified file.

I have gone through various websites and tried many things

**Code**:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <style>
            body {
                cursor: url("C:\Users\ashut\Desktop\cursor.png"), pointer;
            }
        </style>
    </body>
</html>
```

I expected to see the custom cursor I had created, but I get the following error message:

> GET file:///C:/Usersshut%C3%9Esktop%0Cursor.png 
>   net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND.

Comment: Did you try changing \ to / or escaping it?

Comment: Did u try using relative referencing instead?

Comment: @lv Misticos i did try changing \ to / and escaping it

Comment: change it to `file:///C:/Users/ashut/Desktop/cursor.png` seems like you are using wrong url pattern. Open the same url in your browser and see if it opens up, if it does, right click on the url and copy that entire path and use it in your CSS. Generally you dont use this file based URL

Comment: @Martin thanks for pointing that out, updated

Comment: now copy and paste it into an answer `;-)`